# Converting Tiff obect from BitMiracle LibTiff to NET types

Tags: c#, tiff, libtiff.net

On client side I have image in TIFF images with multiple pages.

Firt I convert this image file to byte array and then I sent this data to web service.

For converting TIFF to byte array I use method `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes`.

On web service side I would like convert this byte array to
If byte array contains invalid data it will be nice to have som control.

Then I need do these things:

- parse all pages from multi TIFF image to objects type of `System.Drawing.Image`
- get specified images from multi TIFF
- convert `BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic.Tiff` object to byte array
- save `BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic.Tiff` object to disk in TIFF format

I google it, tried many samples but for me is bit problem convert byte array to 
`BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic.Tiff` (and back) and convert `BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic.Tiff`object which hold multi TIFF to
collection of `System.Drawing.Image`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two samples that show how to create `System.Drawing.Image` from a TIFF

- [Convert color TIFF to a 32-bit System.Drawing.Bitmap](https://github.com/BitMiracle/libtiff.net/tree/master/Samples/TiffTo32BitBitmap)
- [Convert color TIFF to a 24-bit System.Drawing.Bitmap](https://github.com/BitMiracle/libtiff.net/tree/master/Samples/TiffTo24BitBitmap)

These samples create `System.Drawing.Image` for the *current* page of a TIFF. By default, current page is the first page.

In case your TIFF image is multipage you still can use the code from samples. But you will need to encapsulate the code in a method and call that method multiple times: one time for each page.

The number of pages can be retrieved using [NumberOfDirectories](https://bitmiracle.github.io/libtiff.net/help/api/BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic.Tiff.html#BitMiracle_LibTiff_Classic_Tiff_NumberOfDirectories) method. Current page can be set using [SetDirectory](https://bitmiracle.github.io/libtiff.net/help/api/BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic.Tiff.html#BitMiracle_LibTiff_Classic_Tiff_SetDirectory_System_Int16_) method.

The [How to use a System.IO.Stream to read or write TIFF images](https://github.com/BitMiracle/libtiff.net/tree/master/Samples/UsingSystemIOStream) sample shows how to read TIFF image from a memory stream.

Comment: Great. But one question LibTiff.NEt doesnt have method which parse all pages from multi tiff do another collection? I must parse one by one?

Comment: @whyme Honestly, I am not sure if I understand you right. Do you want to create multipage TIFF from multipage TIFF? Or what?

Comment: No, first I load multi page TIFF to BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic.Tiff object and then I need parse all pages from this object to List<System.Drawing.Image>

Comment: Ok, as I told in the answer, you will need to adapt existing samples and parse pages one by one.